# Using substring in crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a field in crystal report with the following data:
**'605 KL1 - Daniel Steve'**
How can i just remove the **'605 KL1 - '** and leave the **'Daniel Steve'** in the field only?
Characters before **'-'** could be different, i hope the formula would automatically search for the **'- '** and then show everything after it.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`MID` can help here:

```
MID(my_string, 11) // will print your string from character 11 ("D") forward
```

And you can combine `MID` with `INSTR` if you need the display to be dynamic (of course this will only work if your data have a consistent format):

```
MID(my_string, (INSTR(my_string, "-") + 2))
```

Comment: Is it possible not to fixed the character index? As the characters before "-" could be different. I hope it can search for the '- ' and then show anything after '- '.

Comment: @WeeShian:  just added another example to address this additional case.

Answer (score 7):

**Use Subscript (x[y]) Crystal Syntaxsub**

```
field_name ='605 KL1 - Daniel Steve'
```

The syntaxis `{field_name}` [11 to 23]

`Result = {field_name}` [11 to 23]  -> Result = `'Daniel Steve'`

Website reference: 
[IBM - Developing Crystal Report](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/rsawshlp/v7r5m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.businessobjects.integration.eclipse.designer.doc/html/topic867.html)

Answer (score 2):

I think u can also use `Split` function like that

```
Split ({field_name},"-")[2]
```

But if you want to use split function,u must make sure delimiter exist in the string or add some condition to prevent runtime error. Split function returns an array but it's doesn't start with zero. Its mean `[1]` is first room and `[2]` is second room.